# byte/short Vs int as for loop counter variable

Tags: java, for-loop

Is it a good practice to use byte/short as counter variable when we know the exact number of loops?
for example

```
for (byte i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
```

vs

```
for (short i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
```

vs

```
 for (int i = 1; i <=26; i++)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is more likely to be confusing than helpful.  Most developers expect to see an `int` value and you only have 32-bit or 64-bit registers in your CPU so it won't change how your program works or performs.

There are many options which work and are not harmful to your program but you need to think about the poor developer who has to read it and understand it later, this could be you 6 months from now. ;)

It is also not worth making such a change even if the performance were faster unless it was dramatically faster.  Consider this change.

```
for (byte i = 1; i <= 120; i++)
```

or

```
for (byte i = 1; i <= x; i++)
```

You might thing this is fine as 200 < 2^8 and it compiles just fine, but it's actually an infinite loop.

You have to ask the question; How much faster does it have to be, if you increase the risk of introducing a bug later?

Usually the answer is it has to make my whole program significantly faster in a way I have measured (not just the bit you change) AND I have to need it to be significantly faster.

Comment: @Masud Correct, that's my point, it still compiles just fine ;)

Comment: @MaheshVarma It is usual to know when changes can improvement performance and when you should avoid using such tricks.  In this case, it doesn't help, but other tricks can help in other situations, but you might still avoid them if they are not needed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The byte type is not sufficient for the number of intended loops.

Comment: @iheanyi You are right that 200 is too large for a signed byte.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** No, because CPU's are optimized for integer operations. If you work with bytes or shorts, the CPU constantly has to convert it to integers and back, generally by applying bitmasks.

Comment: CPUs have native byte and short operations and they not any slower than int operations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Sounds interesting. Do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, Thanks a lot, Very helpful to my project, may I ask a reference to this (CPU's are optimized for integer operations)?

Answer (score 3):

When you perform some operations on short or byte variable you have to explicitly typecast it back to the required type in java. So it is preferred to use int in place of byte and short.
Example :

```
short s = 0;
s= (short) (s+10);
```

If you do not typecast it to int it will throw compile time error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to short` So it is preferred to use int.

Comment: I am sure there will be no operations on them @nishu

Comment: Internally short and byte will be treated as int only. For readiness you can use short or byte, doesn't matter. I am not sure if it will have any performance issues.You are incrementing short and byte everytime in the loop so you are doing operations.It looks like typecasting is done in case of ++ operator internally. i++ can be rewritten as i = (short)(i+1);

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.

byte and short variables are 32bit/64bit size at this point and the VM is optimized for int.

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: I'm giving a point for this comment because it targets the JVM, not the CPU architecture. Am I odd for not caring about the underlying architecture when I'm programming against a virtual machine which should be shielding me from such things? My initial instinct was to do it anyway, but I trained myself to just think that Java IS the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If range of data type not exceed in your scenario. There is no issue in both cases.

But `int` is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It also takes a row of memory which usually is 4 or 8 bytes.
This means there will be no optumization for memory usage too.

Also If your system uses fragmentation algos for deviding rows of memory to partial addressing of these values, Its adressing algorithm will cost much!

Answer (score -1):

As a starting point, use `int` which is probably native to the architecture and you'll avoid possible implicit conversions when comparing `i` with other bits and pieces. So my bet is that both `byte` and `short` will wind up being *slower*.

A far cuter optimisation would be to use `++i` rather than `i++`, as the former will never be slower than the latter. (Conceptually `i++` has to return a copy even though it will be optimised out by a good java compiler).

Comment: a byte in Java is an 8-bit signed integer.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Oops you're correct. I was thinking about char. I'll amend after a coffee.